# How to make a condition to see if an href with a certain value was created

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code`<a href="#original" data-toggle="tab"><strong>text</strong></a>`
The a href="#original is created when i click a certain button, now my question is how do I make a condition to see if this certain a href was created?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("[attribute$='#original'").length) {
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

This is what I made so far.

Comment: `$("[href$='#original'").length` in place of `attribute` use `href`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ( $("a[href='#original']").length ) {
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

use the attribute href to find it

Comment: what is the console you're receiving?

Comment: if you are not particular about href value, then utilize [href!='']

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
    if ($("[href$='#original'").length ) 
    {
        console.log($('a').attr('href'));
    }
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_end_value.asp